# Об изучении python 3

Tags: книги, python-3.x

Можете посоветовать книгу или лучше подскажите сайты вроде [Codeacademy](cadeacadey.com) по изучению Python 3. Именно python 3.

Comment: Python 3.4

Comment: @Harry_Potter228, Вопросы опросники в сообществе запрещены. Перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не могу сказать, на сколько она выделяется на фоне остальных, сейчас я читаю "Лутц М. - Изучаем Python (4-е издание)", вроде неплохая, там к тому же рассматриваются различия между 2 и 3 Python, ИМХО это хорошо и полезно, но делается упор на 3. В книге автор часто повторяет то, что уже рассказывал, это неплохо т.к. повторение - как говорится...

Answer (score 0):

checkio.org
Задачи на любой уровень практически, в том числе и на русском языке, подробное описание и подсказки.
Но некоторые знания придётся искать самому.
на stepic.org был курс по 3 питону, но там самые основы + задачки, местами весело.